# ChangeListener for multiple selection TableView in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, changelistener

Say I have a model `Contact`, and TableView representative of that model:

```
class Contact {
    public String name;
    ...
}

@FXML public TableView<Contact> tableView;
```

Then I have a `ChangeListener` to detect selection changed in the table:

```
private ChangeListener<Contact> tableView_ChangeListener = new ChangeListener<Contact>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Contact> observable, Contact oldValue, Contact newValue) {

    ....
    }
};

tableView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(tableView_ChangeListener);
```

Code above works flawlessly for me, up until recently I need a `TableView` that accepts multiple selection:

```
tableView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
```

With `ChangeListener` above, I get `NullPointerException` when I select multiple rows in the table, any workaround?
Thanks!

Comment: If there's a null pointer exception, there's something wrong with the code that you haven't shown. Which line throws the null pointer exception? In general, to track multiple selection you would add a `ListChangeListener` to `tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()`.